# How to draw one object within another and never move outside of that object

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs

i am working with fabric js and i want to draw two objects within canvas and when second object is drawn it should be drawn inside first object and never move outside the first object.I have tried this code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('demo');
    var rec = new fabric.Rect({
        width: 200,
        height: 100,
        top: 10,
        fill: 'blue',
    });
    rec.name = 'aaa';
    canvas.add(rec);


    canvas.on('object:moving', function (e) {
        var h = rec.top;
        var w = rec.width;

        var obj = e.target;
         obj.setCoords();   
        var rect = obj.getBoundingRect;

        if(rect > h){

            rect.top = Math.max(rect.top, rect.top-rect.getBoundingRect().top);
          //  alert(rect.top);

        }

    });
var text=new fabric.IText('Jayesh');
canvas.add(text);
});
```

Thanks in advance.Pls help